# Android: Arrangements in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Got two questions:

1. Is it possible to arrange the items in the sqlite database and display it in list view according to the item that is entered last? I mean the latest data entered is at the top and the older datas are at the bottom?
2. And is it also possible to compile all the data in the database under the same recipient? I mean, all Jack's messages is compiled as one, then Mary's messages is also compiled, not the type of messages/data that are scattered even with the same recipient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes put a time stamp and when you are querying the database sort in descending order for time stamp
2. Not sure about the question being asked, this can be done with your own schema for each contact, you will have to read from the ContactProvider and write to your database

Comment: How do I put timestamp in it? Do you have any sample codes that i can study?